# How to implement group chatting in flutter using agora

Tags: flutter, dart, agora

Im trying to implement group chatting using agora in my flutter app.. anybody know how I can go about that?

Comment: Maybe [this doc](https://docs.agora.io/en/agora-chat/client-api/chat-group/manage-chat-groups?platform=flutter) can help you out.